# Why is my editor template simply not rendering?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my editor template for displaying a fixed list of provinces with a checkbox for each province:

```
@model Comair.RI.UI.Models.ApplicantRelocateProvinceList
<table>
    <tr>
        <th style="display: none;"></th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.HeaderItem.Province)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.HeaderItem.WillRelocate)
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(m => item)
    }
</table>
```

This is the editor template for the `Model.Items` type model:

```
@model Comair.RI.UI.Models.ApplicantRelocateProvinceItem
<tr>
    <td style="display: none;">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Province.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.WillRelocate)
    </td>
</tr>
```

I have used this model successfully for other view models. Here is the `ApplicantRelocateProvinceList` model:

```
public class ApplicantRelocateProvinceList : ViewModel
{        
    public ApplicantRelocateProvinceItem HeaderItem { get; set; }
    public ApplicantRelocateProvinceList()
    {
        HeaderItem = new ApplicantRelocateProvinceItem();
    }
    public void MapFromEntityList(IEnumerable<ApplicantRelocateProvince> applicantProvinces)
    {
        var service = new ProvinceService(DbContext);
        var selectedIds = applicantProvinces.Select(ap => ap.ProvinceId);
        Items = service.ReadProvinces()
                       .Where(i => !i.IsDeleted)
                       .Select(p => new ApplicantRelocateProvinceItem {Id = p.Id, Province = p, WillRelocate = selectedIds.Contains(p.Id)});
    }
    public IEnumerable<ApplicantRelocateProvinceItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

This code reads a fixed list of our nine provinces, and a variable list of provinces chosen by the applicant. Those of the fixed provinces whose IDs are in the applicant's provinces are marked with their `WillRelocate` flag as true, to show its checkbox as checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think problem could be in this line:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => item)
```

Try this:

```
@Html.EditorForModel(item)
```

Similar question: [Why not use Html.EditorForModel()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537220/why-not-use-html-editorformodel)

**Added:**

Special folder must be named `EditorTemplates`, parent folder must be named as controller (for example `Home`) or `Shared` (for all controllers) and view name must be `ApplicantRelocateProvinceItem.cshtml` as class name.

Comment: That would be `@Html.EditorForModel(item)`, as `EditorForModel` won't take a lambda; it wants a plain, whole object.  Anyway, it still doesn't work. Time to get some 3d party widgets.

Comment: @ProfK Thanks, also check your special folder (`EditorTemplates`), parent folder must be for this controller or `Shared` and view name must be `ApplicantRelocateProvinceItem.cshtml`

Comment: It was indeed a one letter typo in the template name. Thanks for the reminder. Always copy and paste after typing only once!