# How should I call `EditorForModel` with its parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Before posting this question, I googled for `EditorForModel` using parameters.

I read [Why not use Html.EditorForModel()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537220/why-not-use-html-editorformodel) and this [blog](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html).

I didn't find any articles related to my needs.

Can you provide me an example of a call to `EditorForModel` with parameters?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There are [6 overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorformodel%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) of this helper:

1. `@Html.EditorForModel()`

   Renders the `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/TypeName.cshtml` template where `TypeName` is the exact type name of your view model. If your view model is a collection (i.e. `IEnumerable<TypeName>`, `IList<TypeName>`, `TypeName[]`, ...) ASP.NET MVC will automatically render the corresponding editor template for each element of the collection. You don't need to be writing any loops in your views for that to happen. It is handled by the framework for you.
2. `@Html.EditorForModel("templatename")`

   Renders `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/templatename.cshtml` instead of relying on the convention
3. `@Html.EditorForModel(new { Foo = "bar" })`

   Renders the default editor template but passes an additional view data to it that you could use inside with `ViewData["foo"]` or `ViewBag.Foo`
4. `@Html.EditorForModel("templatename", new { Foo = "bar" })`

   Renders `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/templatename.cshtml` instead of relying on the convention and passes an additional view data to it that you could use inside with `ViewData["foo"]` or `ViewBag.Foo`
5. `@Html.EditorForModel("templatename", "fieldprefix")`

   Renders `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/templatename.cshtml` instead of relying on the convention and modifies the navigational context inside this template, meaning that for example if you had an `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FooBar)` call inside this template you would get `name="fieldprefix.FooBar"` instead of `name="FooBar"`
6. `@Html.EditorForModel("templatename", "fieldprefix", new { Foo = "bar" })`

   Renders `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/templatename.cshtml` instead of relying on the convention and modifies the navigational context inside this template, meaning that for example if you had an `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FooBar)` call inside this template you would get `name="fieldprefix.FooBar"` instead of `name="FooBar"`. It also passes an additional view data to it that you could use inside with `ViewData["foo"]` or `ViewBag.Foo`

Remark: The templating system will first look for templates in `~/Views/XXX/EditorTemplates` where XXX is the name of the controller that served this view and if it doesn't find it will look into `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates`. This could allow for more fine-grained tweaking of the templates. You could have default templates in the shared folder that could be overridden per controller basis.