# ASP.NET Core Running Multiple Templates when using @Html.EditorForModel()

Tags: partial-views, asp.net-core-2.1, mvc-editor-templates

I have an EditorTemplate for booleans:

```
@model bool?
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox ">
        <input asp-for="@Model"/>
        <label asp-for="@Model"></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I have a Model similar to this:

```
public class FooModel
{
    public bool IsFoo { get; set; }
    public bool IsBar { get; set; }
    public bool IsBaz { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to render the templates individually for the properties

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.FooModel.IsFoo)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.FooModel.IsBar)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.FooModel.IsBaz)
```

...I get what I'm expecting:

[image: Screenshot of expected]

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox ">
     <input type="checkbox" data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsFoo field is required." id="FooModel_IsFoo" name="FooModel.IsFoo" value="true"> 
     <label for="FooModel_IsFoo">IsFoo</label>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- same for IsBar and IsBaz -->
```

... but when I try to take a "shortcut" and let the framework handle it

```
@Html.EditorForModel() //  model is FooModel
```

I get all kinds of weirdness.  The labels are "doubled up" because (I believe) the framework is running its own template *and* my template.

[image: Screenshot of unexpected result]

```
<div class="editor-label">
  <label for="CsosTypeFilter_IsFoo">IsFoo</label>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
  <!-- contents of my template are here, removed for brevity --> 
  <span data-valmsg-for="CsosTypeFilter.IsFoo" 
        data-valmsg-replace="true" 
        class="field-validation-valid">
  </span>
</div>
<!-- same for IsBar and IsBaz -->
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this?  Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: `Html.EditorForModel()` is really only useful for basic scaffolding. The only way to make it work for a custom template is to define an editor template for the entire class, which pretty much defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

What if you use the overload:

`@Html.EditorForModel(m => m, "template") //  model is FooModel, template is your template`

Comment: I don't have a template defined for `FooModel`, just for the `boolean` properties.  If I define a template for `FooModel`, then I'm just moving all the code I'm still manually writing the `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.IsFoo)  ...` to another file vs. getting rid of it entirely.

Comment: I missunderstood the question. Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15092998/how-should-i-call-editorformodel-with-its-parameters